# App opens to a blank screen after reopening rather than showing the last opened state

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android development, I have experienced this strange behavior with my app that is whenever I open my app and also parallely open other apps, do some surfing and again open my app after few minutes it will open a blank screen  rather than opening the screen I surfed lastly. Again to access the app I need to forcefully stop the app and restart it again. Please help me with this. I am using Android studio for my development.

This is my gradle file when I have removed the firebase and android gms-playservices related dependencies its working fine but not when these two are included.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "teletextholidaysapp.com.teletextholidaysandroid"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code - without seeing your code, we can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hi @JonasCz can you please tell me the code ur asking to share with because, I am experiencing this behavior throughout my application